# Does energy resistance from my class and race stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stacking, resistance

In the rules it says resistance doesn't stack with spells but if I get resistance from my race and if I have resistance with my class (Ex: Efreeti bloodline) does the resistance stacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

Energy Resistance needs to say whether it stacks and, if so, with which other resistances it stacks.
The rules text about Energy Resistance is fairly short, but in general you can assume that it is meant to work like the more detailed Damage Reduction mechanic. These two abilities are basically two sides of the same coin, one representing defense against energy damage types and the other against physical damage types.

> [Damage Reduction](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Damage-Reduction)
>
> If a creature has damage reduction from more than one source, the two forms of damage reduction do not stack. Instead, the creature gets the benefit of the best damage reduction in a given situation.

Sometimes abilities tell you to increase a resistance, but this isn't the case with the Efreeti bloodline either.

So in the end your highest energy resistance applies.

---

However, In some situations it might be useful to keep details in mind about your energy resistances, for example:

- The [Studied Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Studied%20Spell) metamagic would allow an enemy caster to ignore your racial energy resistance, while the energy resistance from your Efreeti bloodline would be unaffected by that metamagic.
- If your energy resistance is an (Ex)traordinary, (Sp)ell-like, (Su)pernatural, or Natural Ability, then it interacts differently with certain environments, e.g. (Sp) and (Su) abilities don't work inside antimagic fields, while (Ex) & (Su) abilities (that depend on form) are lost when under the effects of certain [Polymorph spells](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDefinitions.aspx?ID=20).

Unless you want to keep a redundant resistance, consider exchanging a racial energy resistance trait for an alternate racial trait, if you intend a build that gives you the same energy resistance from another source. For example, a [Tiefling](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tiefling) could exchange his Fiendish Resistance with the Scaled Skin trait:

> **Fiendish Resistance:** Tieflings have cold resistance 5, electricity resistance 5, and fire resistance 5.

> **Scaled Skin:** The skin of these tieflings provides some energy resistance, but is also as hard as armor. Choose one of the following energy types: cold, electricity, or fire. A tiefling with this trait gains resistance 5 in the chosen energy type and also gains a +1 natural armor bonus to AC.
> This racial trait replaces fiendish resistance.

Comment: While I agree with the interpretation on principle, I think it'd be worth noting that the rules really don't say so, and GM's making other interpretations is perfectly valid.